# Trying to build a model to suggest related questions

Tags: deep-learning, recommender-system

I am trying to build a model which can recommend/predict a followup question based on the previous question.

Like "Did you attend the college?"

a followup question may be "What was your major at college?"

I am trying to build a deep learning model for the same. A approach that seems possible is using "Seq2Seq" model over a related dataset. Any intuition or possible idea. It is more like recommendation model but they are not working properly.

Comment: This question could be more appropriate for SO.